# How to generate a list of number in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.0

How to create a list of num from 1 to 10
Example:

```
int[] values = Enumerable.Range(1,max).ToArray();
MessageBox.Show(values+",");
```

The output should be:
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code is generating array of integers from 1 to 10

```
int[] values = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray();
```

but you're displaying them in wrong way (you're trying to cast int array to string), change it to

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", values);
```

[`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) will join your values separating them with `,`

In .Net <4.0 you should use (and I believe OP is using one)

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", values.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: It return an error Error 2 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'string[]' Please help I'm new to C#

Comment: @ZeroX sorry, changed answer, I forgot to cast int to string

Comment: Still return an error Error 2 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah, but why isn't? I checked and string.Join accepts IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @ZeroX you should be using .Net at least 4.0

Comment: @ZeroX I Changed my answer to target previous versions of .Net

Comment: @ZeroX glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> values = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", values.Select(x => x.ToString())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below using the generic version of `Join<T>()` method.

```
        int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join<int>(",", arr));
```

Generate `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

(OR) using good old `foreach` loop

```
        string str = string.Empty;
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            str += i.ToString() + ",";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(str.TrimEnd(','));
```

Comment: Error 1 The non-generic method 'string.Join(string, string[])' cannot be used with type arguments Still getting error

Comment: There is something wrong at your end. Which framework version you are on? This works fine for me.

Comment: I'm using microsoft visual C# 2008 :3

Comment: @ZeroX, Not sure but may be you are using framework version 3 or lower probably.

Comment: @ZeroX, see edit in answer with the normal looping approach.